# Save spark DataFrame to csv file with map<string,string> column type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, scala-collections

I have wrote udf function that convert Map[String,String] values to String:

```
 udf("mapToString", (input: Map[String,String]) => input.mkString(","))
```

`spark-shell` give me error:

```
    <console>:24: error: overloaded method value udf with alternatives:
  (f: AnyRef,dataType: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType)org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction <and> 
...
cannot be applied to (String, Map[String,String] => String)
       udf("mapToString", (input: Map[String,String]) => input.mkString(","))
```

Is any method to convert column of Map[String,String] values to string values?
I need this conversion because i need save dataframe as csv file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `DataFrame` as

```
+---+--------------+
|id |map           |
+---+--------------+
|1  |Map(200 -> DS)|
|2  |Map(300 -> CP)|
+---+--------------+
```

with the following schema

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- map: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

You can write a `udf` which looks like :

```
def mapToString = udf((map: collection.immutable.Map[String, String]) => 
                       map.mkString.replace(" -> ", ","))
```

and use the `udf` function with `withColumn` API as

```
df.withColumn("map", mapToString($"map"))
```

you should have final `DataFrame` where `Map` is changed to `String`

```
+---+------+
|id |map   |
+---+------+
|1  |200,DS|
|2  |300,CP|
+---+------+

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- map: string (nullable = true)
```